# Angular material 2 - Set manually a field/control as invalid

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am doing a nested reactive form. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10508) about setting automatically the classes that mark the field as invalid (with red color),  when the form controls are in different components.

These classes are `mat-form-field-invalid`and `mat-input-invalid`.

So my idea to solve this is to get from the FormGroup the invalid controls after clicking on the submit button, and in a loop match them with the formControlName of the invalid controls/fields **and set them programatically as invalid**.

I tried with `formData.form.controls['formControlName'].markAsTouched();` and other similar "solutions" that I found here and googling but any of them works.

How can I do it?

I'm using Angular Material 5.2.4.

Comment: Have you tried `setErrors()`?

Comment: @G.Tranter Yes, I tried it but it doesn't works. In a moment I will answer a question with one WorkArround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, what I did to add the CSS error classes to the fields that are invalid in my nested reactive form:

```
 this.invalidControls(this.formGroup); //Call it just after submit the form

 //The implementation of the function
 invalidControls(name): void {
    for (const field in name.controls) {
      const control = name.get(field);

      if(control.constructor.name == "FormArray" || control.constructor.name == "FormGroup"){
        this.invalidControls(control); //If the AbstractControl is not a FormControl the funtion will be called again
      }
      else{
        if(control.status === "INVALID"){
          control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
          control.markAsDirty({ onlySelf: true });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So if you set the control as **invalid**, **dirty**, and it's **empty**, the CSS error classes will be added. Otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks, it's by far the most simple workaround and works in the parent component as well.

Comment: I don't see a point, you are checking if the control.status is INVALID, doesn't that make the control invalid already? I have a situation where a non-form related field as to be set invalid, but the status field of `FormControl` is read-only.